# How can I do off screen rendering using LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to find a way to do rendering off screen with LWJGL. What I want to do is render something and keep it in memory as a texture, then at a later point use that to texture a shape I'm drawing in the main window. I'm pretty sure this should be done using a Frame Buffer Object, but I haven't been able to find any useful documentation online. I'm fairly new to Open GL and LWJGL so I'm sure there is some fundamental concept I'm missing.

Could someone possibly provide a simple example that renders something(I don't really care what) off screen to a texture? Ideally I would like to end up with a slick-util Texture object.

Answer (score 2):

Create a frame buffer object and bind it as the primary render target.  Here is a tutorial:

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/opengl-frame-buffer-object-101-r2331

Comment: Please provide a full working example. Your answers shouldn't break if the links do.